# Nativescript debug console message after starting debug on ios

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, output, nativescript-angular

Im getting the following message when start debugging in VSC debugger.

Error when trying to require webpack.config.js file from path '/Volumes/T7/Documents/1.Sources/app/webpack.config.js'. Error is: TypeError: host.onUnRecoverableConfigFileDiagnostic is not a function

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your `@nativescript/webpack` to latest (at time of this write it would be 4.0.0) and also update your `webpack.config.js` using the command `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs`, also check if you have to update deps using `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps`

Answer (score 0):

I did get the same issue on android debug with VS code
nativescript extension 0.1